# What's the exact definition of little o notation

Tags: real-analysis, notation, asymptotics

I have seen the following definitions of little-o notation,

$(1)$ Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
. Then I say $f(x)=o(g(x))$ iff,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$$.

$(2)$ On the other hand I have also seen this definition on some websites,
If $f(x)=o(g(x))$. Then there exists a $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$f(x)\leq k g(x)$$ for all $x\geq x_{0}$ for some $x_{0}\in\mathbb{R}$

**My question:-**

I was just wondering how are they both equivalent. I am unable to get the intuition behind. How to understand this equivalence intuitively?

Comment: It's clear that these definitions are not equivalent. Take $f=g=1$ to see that (2) doesn't imply (1).

Comment: I got the fault in my question as mentioned by @John White.

Comment: As an English sentence, the one you've written in (2) looks more like a theorem than a definition, the theorem being the true statement that $f\in o(g)\Rightarrow f\in O(g)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first definition is for little-o but the second one seems to be for big-O

Comment: Does little o have any meanings in terms of inequalities?

Comment: It should be $f(x) = o(g(x))$ if $\textbf{for every}$ $k \in \mathbb{R}^+$, there exists $x_0$ s.t. $f(x) \leq k g(x)$

Comment: @JohnWhite You mean $f(x)=O(g(x))$

Comment: @PNT little o is same as big O where the constant can be any epsilon, that's why John wrote "for every k" (unheard, especially arbitrary small).